C++ Qt best way to loop over a vector that is a member of a vector of parent dummy objects also being looped over
I want to loop over a vector of objects each containing another vector of objects to be looped over in turn. The subvector/contained vector object members need to be able to be able to be modified and not copy constructed or implicitly shared. They are accessed from different worker methods. See the code below. Does this work? If not what's the best way to do this?
class Worker : public QObject
{
    public:
    void backup();
    void startScans();
    void startBackups();

    private:
    QVector<BackupJob> jobs;
}

class BackupJob
{
    public:
    QVector<BackupJob> getSubJobs() { return subJobs; }

    private:
    QVector<BackupJob> subJobs;
}

void Worker::backup()
{
    startScans();
    startBackups();
}

void Worker::startScans()
{
    for (BackupJob& job : jobs)
        for (BackupJob& subJob : job.getSubJobs())
            //do scans on each subjob here
}

void Worker::startBackups()
{
    for (BackupJob& job : jobs)
        for (BackupJob& subJob : job.getSubJobs())
            //do backups on each subjob here
}


You can do it like this, but be aware that getSubJobs() is returning a copy of the vector. Perhaps that's okay with Qt's QVector, as it does have implicit sharing to ensure copy construction is fast. You may want to consider providing a backup() method for BackupJob too, and call that recursively, instead of expecting Worker to deal with the details. That allows BackupJob to stay in control of its private members without needing to make them available via accessors.

Sorry I didn't clarify that I need those subvectors modified from different methods in the Worker object. I edited the question appropriately.

It'd help if you added dummy modifying code. Also, are you modifying the vectors, or the objects in the vector?

I'd consider either making Worker friend of BaxkupJob, or change the getter to getSubJobsRef() which returns a reference to the vector.

I'd also consider changing the vectors to maps, if there is an easy unique id to use as a key. That would make things easier as then each job would have a clear identity, making manipulating it more robust.

Problem description is to poor to provide nice full answer, but I have no doubt that proper answer to your problem is recursion. There must be a function which will be invoked with new list of subJobs which will iterate over sub jobs and invoke itself for a children of each item.

@hyde I'm modifying the BackupJob objects in the subJobs vector. I'd considered returning a reference but wasn't sure if that was a "proper" way of doing things. Like it might be considered taboo.

@MarekR Can you give a tiny bit of code? Thx

You're breaking the principle of encapsulation here, by expecting one class to know about the innards of another. It's unclear what "modifications" you need to do, but surely those operations can be defined via a public interface.

@paddy Thanks I knew something was wrong there... can you think of any design patterns or data structures I could employ? A qMap stored in the Worker object with job name keys and QVector subJob list values is one obvious option as hyde mentioned. To add more info about this situation ... the jobs QVector stores dummy jobs with job options and the subJobs QVector stores job objects, one for each directory to operate on. I just create the subJobs copy constructed off the main job from the jobs QVector. Thus the elegance of a subJobs member QVector and range based for loops.

You didn't provide any clue what //do scans on each subjob here is doing so I will make up something.
Lets say Worker should write this tree of jobs as an xml to some stream. Since tree is large SAX must be used.
Fixing your data structure, so copies are not created. QVector uses COW (Copy On Write), so this is not a big problem, but it is better to be safe then sorry:
class BackupJob
{
public:
    const QVector<BackupJob>& getSubJobs() const
    {
        return subJobs;
    }

private:
    QVector<BackupJob> subJobs;
};

Worker (renamed):
class JobsXmlWriter : public QObject
{
public:
    explicit JobsXmlWriter(
            QVector<BackupJob> jobs,
            QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{parent}
        , jobs{std::move(jobs)}
    {}

public slots:
    void writeInto(QIODevice* out)
    {
        QXmlStreamWriter xml{out};
        writeInto(&xml);
    }

    void writeInto(QXmlStreamWriter* xml)
    {
        xml->writeStartDocument();
        xml->writeStartElement("jobsTree");
          
        for (const auto& job : jobs) {
           writeJobRecursive(xml, job);
        }
        xml.writeEndElement();
        xml.writeEndDocument();
    }

private:
    void writeJobRecursive(QXmlStreamWriter* xml, const BackupJob& current)
    {
        xml->writeStartElement("job");
        writeJobDetail(xml, job);
        writeJobChildren(xml, job);
        xml->writeEndElement();
    }

    void writeJobDetail(QXmlStreamWriter* xml, const BackupJob& current)
    {
        xml->writeAttribute("name", current.getName());
    }

    void writeJobChildren(QXmlStreamWriter* xml, const BackupJob& current)
    {
        xml->writeStartElement("children");
        for (const auto& subJob : current.getSubJobs()) {
           writeJobRecursive(xml, subJob);
        }
        xml->writeEndElement();
    }

private:
    QVector<BackupJob> jobs;
};

As you can see recursion is able to iterate over whole tree and write data to xml.
It is possible to write iterative version, but this is more complex. This may be necessary only if tree of your jobs is very deep (for example tree is unbalanced).

I see where you're going now, sorry it wasn't clear to me at first. The thing there is only one subJobs vector; it's only one level deep so recursion isn't necessary.
